# Xcode 4.3.3valid provisioning profiles

Tags: xcode, certificate, provisioning, portal

In Xcode 4.3.3 I am able to submit my app to the app store and it is "waiting for review."  I deleted my app from my device(iPad) then I decided I wanted it back on.  I cannot not accomplish this.  Xcode says the build is a success but then a message stating "no valid provisioning profiles for this executable can be found" appears.  it does not appear as a red flag in Xcode but rather it's own window.

I've never dealt with such a frustrating apple product as Xcode and the provisioning portal and code signing. Apple, do something about this never ending circle of frustration. UGH!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I felt this way too when I first learned this:

> I've never dealt with such a frustrating apple product as Xcode and
>   the provisioning portal and code signing.

If you just submitted the app to the App Store, you used a **distribution** profile. You should check to make sure, though, that your **developer** profile is still working. Click on your project in Xcode at the top of the left column, then Build Settings > Code Signing > Code Signing Identity > Debug > Any iOS SDK. It should say something like:

> iPhone Developer (currently matches 'iPhone Developer blah blah blah')

If it doesn't say that, select your profile from the drop down list. If there's no matching profile. You need to download it again. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Woz, thanks for the reply and the comment about accepting answers. i am away from that computer now but when i get in i will check out what you said to do.  I was also wondering what is my 'target'  would that be my iPad or iPod?  I'm confused with that.

Comment: also did i accept your answer? I'm not sure how to do that.  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Woz,  started my project in Xcode and named it test1.  i never thought i'd actually get a functioning app. but once i wanted the app to show up on my device with a better name so I changed the project name. would this effected?

Comment: @AnthonyArtillondio 1) A target is your compiled program. You usually just have one per project, but you could have more if you wanted to compile the app different ways. 2) Yes, you accepted my answer. Thanks!3) Changing the product name may have caused it; you really should never change that. To change to name you see on the device under the icon, select your project from the left menu, then your target, then the "Info" tab, then change "Bundle display name". It probably says `${PRODUCT_NAME}` right now, but you can erase that and put your own.

Comment: ok, that's great! thank you i wasn't aware of that.  the last week has ended with me getting the same message over and over.

Comment: oops..here's the message. "No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates."  i've read lots of posts and tried everything.  i am at a total loss.  i moved my project to a new computer and i still have no success. and the worst part is, i was past this point. i mean i have an app waiting for review, but now i can't even deploy it to my device. it runs great in the simulators.  Thanks again for everything

Comment: Did your profile get deleted or moved, or did it expire? If you moved to another computer, you probably need to download the profile again and load it up in Xcode. I know it seems like it's totally broken, but you are probably only a small step away from fixing it.

Comment: I think I'm really close but I've been stuck here for so long.  i created a duplicate project from the original file on an external drive.  and now the duplicate is on my iMac(my mane computer which is where I'm having the problems).  I feel like i've done everything but maybe I'm forgetting something.  I'm sure i did it already but where would i download the profile? the  provisioning portal? i've gone to the provisioning portal and through key chain access and through provisioning profiles so many times.  i feel dizzy. at night i go outside and walk around and try to think out the....

Comment: process after giving up on the computer. i've even had several dreams of things to try in the provisioning portal. this is a strange place I'm in. thank you for all of your help woz! i refuse to give up.

Comment: Yes, I have had that before. Sometimes it's best to take a break and come back. If you go to the Provisioning Portal, the development profile should be right there under the "Provisioning" tab on the left. Just download it, click on the file, and it will open in Xcode's organizer. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Thanks Woz! I'm at work the until sunday and i will be at Xcode bright and early.  my blood pressure was soaring so i took a day away from it. i will keep you posted and thanks for the help!!

Comment: well, before i had a chance to jump back in to the portal i received news that apple had rejected my app. so i am so depressed at this news. i think i may post their reasons why. but on the other hand i don't think i have any need to continue with this Xcode problem. i was barely able to get an app together in the first place. the worst part is was that my app functioned great they just said in a nut shell that it sucked. oh well. another notch on the rejection list.